# How to divide dataframe row's each value by row's total sum (data normalization) in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe of user's preferences:

```
+-------+-----+-----+-----+
|user_id|Movie|Music|Books|
+-------+-----+-----+-----+
|   100 |  0  |  1  |  2  |
|   101 |  3  |  1  |  4  |
+-------+---------+-------+
```

How to 1) compute total sum of each row(user); 2) divide each value by that sum? so I get normalized preference values:

```
+-------+---- -+-------+-------+
|user_id| Movie| Music | Books |
+-------+----- +-------+-------+
|   100 |  0   | 0.33..| 0.66..|
|   101 |0.42..| 0.15..| 0.57..|
+-------+------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# get column names that need to be normalized
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col != 'user_id']

# sum the columns by row
rowsum = sum([df[x] for x in cols])

# select user_id and normalize other columns by rowsum
df.select('user_id', *((df[x] / rowsum).alias(x) for x in cols)).show()

+-------+-----+------------------+------------------+
|user_id|Movie|             Music|             Books|
+-------+-----+------------------+------------------+
|    100|  0.0|0.3333333333333333|0.6666666666666666|
|    101|0.375|             0.125|               0.5|
+-------+-----+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly! May I ask how to divide row's each value by maximum number in the row?

Comment: replace `rowsum` line with `greatest = f.greatest(*(df[x] for x in cols))` where `import pyspark.sql.functions as f`.

Comment: It somehow finds wrong greatest value, so after dividing I have some values greater than 1, which means that the original value was divided by smaller value. It looks like that: ```| 100|  0.0 |1.3333333333333333 | 0.6666666666666666 | ...``` but I supposed there shoudnt be value greater than `1` since the greatest value in the raw divided by `greatest`  should give `1`

Comment: New to PySpark. Can I ask what the `*` means in the select statement?

Comment: `*` has nothing to do with spark. It's a python syntax for spreading multiple parameters into a function call.